# How to show again Azure Function in Portal Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

I created some functions in Azure Portal and for some of them I choose not to show them on Dashboard. Others were removed from Dashboard later at some point.

Now I'd like to show them again on Dashboard, but I cannot seem to find a way to do that. For how much simple that must be, I'm not able to find it.

How do you achieve that? TA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "PIN" icon to the far right of every blade, next to the X button.

That should act as a way to Pin something to your Dashboard.

However, I've found that, depending on the blade, you can get a different icons / different information with your three button technique vs this "PIN" technique.

Comment: That is correct. The three dots indicates a context menu exists on the grid item and usually that contains at least the command "pin to dashboard" in the browse resource context. However, in other resource contexts this menu option may not exist and the more consistent way is to use the "PIN" icon on the top of a blade, as you suggested, in order to pin it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I just found a way, totally by chance.

From left panel menu, All resources. In resource list showing up there, each item has a three-dots button on the left side, holding the command to add that resource to Dashboard.

A screenshot (in Italian):

[image]

Comment: You can do the same from `App Services` menu too

Comment: I would mark Jesse's answer as best answer though because what he says is correct, this command doesn't always exist in every three dot menu. Also as a tip, you can get this menu to show up by right clicking on the row with your mouse.

Comment: No prob to mark it if it gets some more votes than this! I was not implying that every three-dots menu has that command, by the way. Just said *that* menu next to resource item in list had the needed command. Sorry if I was not clear. I'll have to try again with right mouse click, I thought I tried already without success (in MS Edge)